# How to get particular product image in shopify liquid file?

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to call or get particular product image in shopify liquid file?

I mean is it possible to get a particular image through a handle or id. Does liquid have a filter tag for that purpose.

With asset url, this is possible.

`{{ 'my-image.png' | asset_url }}`

But I just wanted to know whether this is possible with product images.

Something like this:
`{{ product.images | product_img_url: 'red-xl-vertical-product' }}`

I hope you got it.

Rather than looping and displaying all the product images I have a used case where a particular product image has to be called on the product page.

Is there an API for getting a particular product image by an id or a handle rather than image index in the `product.liquid` file?

Or can someone suggest alternatives other than storing them in the assets folder?

This is what I've tried. But not working!
`{{ product.images | where: 'id', '1785281087' | img_url }}`

Comment: Is this possible with Shopify liquid?

Comment: This is possible!

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct! Just a slight change will make it working.

**What you missed was you forgot to assign it to a variable in order for filter `where` to work!**

This can be achieved using the following trick:

first you need to assign the product media to a variable

`{% assign images = product.media | where: "alt", "primary-image" %}`

then you can get the `img_tag`

```
<div>
  {{ images[0] | img_tag }}
</div>
```

Here is the complete snippet.

```
{% assign images = product.media | where: "alt", "main-image" %}

<div>
  {{ images[0] | img_tag }}
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add extra ```key: value``` pairs to ```product.media``` object?

Comment: Not sure about that. But you can definitely add ```metafields``` to product, collection & product variants!